# Convert Json to C# Object using Json.net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api, json.net

I've searched many a web site, and deployed various solutions to my web server, only to find that nothing I have come across so far actually works. I have the following JSON:

```
["{\"EntryNo\":4,\"Title\":\"New Title\",\"Summary\":\"New Summary\",\"Body\":\"New Body\",\"CreatedOn\":\"2017-03-03T03:53:16.2955903+00:00\",\"CreatedBy\":\"Jim Jones\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"Jim Jones\",\"ModifiedOn\":\"2017-02-25T07:06:32.517\",\"Deleted\":false,\"TypeId\":1}",
"{\"EntryNo\":5,\"Title\":\"Old Title\",\"Summary\":\"Old Summary\",\"Body\":\"Old Body\",\"CreatedOn\":\"2017-03-03T03:53:16.2955903+00:00\",\"CreatedBy\":\"Ben Jones\",\"ModifiedBy\":\"Ben Jones\",\"ModifiedOn\":\"2017-02-25T07:06:32.593\",\"Deleted\":false,\"TypeId\":1}"
]
```

My Model looks like the following:

```
public class BlogVM
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EntryNo")]
    public int EntryNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CreatedOn")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ModifiedOn")]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CreatedBy")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ModifiedBy")]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Deleted")]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "TypeId")]
    public int? TypeId { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller method is admittedly a hodgepodge...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> _ActualBlogContent()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("wwww.myapiaddresshere.com");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/entry/").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        List<BlogVM> pdone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BlogVM>>(dataObjects.Result);
    }

    return View();
}
```

I'm getting an error message of:

> Could not cast or convert from System.String to Models.Blog.BlogVM

What am I missing? Also, fwiw json2Csharp does not work. All json I pass it fails....But if I validate the son on jsonlint.com, it passes validation testing.

I'm really confused as to what's missing here. Am I just using the framework incorrectly?

Comment: could you paste the full stacktrace?

Comment: why are you not `await`ing the `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.. Its the only reason why you have set the method as an `async Task` anyway. Now I would assume you are not getting the result your expecting.

Comment: is your api returning a json? or a string representation of json? looks like the second

Comment: Dot make API calls directly on controller. Put that in a service class and have it implement an interface that exposes the method you need. Then have your class depend on that interface by taking in an instance in its constructor. And have dependency injection insert an instance of your service class into the controller.

Comment: @mason that is so far from being relevant to a question about a JSON serialization error.

Comment: @Eric It wasn't intended to address to the question asked, or I would have put it in an answer. It is nevertheless good advice. If someone is doing something silly, they should be told. Or do you suggest that we should only address's exactly what is asked? Should we point out SQL Injection Attacks even though a question may not be about that? I've been around a while, I think I'll continue to help spread good practices, thanks.

Comment: @mason I don't disagree with you or your intent, but I think in this context it has the potential to create confusion rather than help the asker address his issue. I think it takes more than a couple sentences to explain the good design concepts you're preaching.

Comment: If he has confusion he's welcome to say so. In the meantime, let's not muck up the comments with speculation about the potential of someone getting confused or the wisdom of giving someone advice about something they didn't ask about.

Comment: I'm seeing an `array` with 2 `strings`.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your JSON is as good as you think it is. I couldn't get what you posted to pass validation, because of some errant quotes in various places.

I ran what you posted through [this JSON formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), and it gave me all kinds of errors, including the error that it was expecting a string. This is because of the `["{` at the very beginning. When deserializing, it expects a brace (`{`), but you gave it a quote (`"`), hence the error message. You have a few places like this where a brace is expected, but a quote is found.

Here is some cleaned up JSON. This should deserialize just fine.

```
[
   {
      "EntryNo":4,
      "Title":"New Title",
      "Summary":"New Summary",
      "Body":"New Body",
      "CreatedOn":"2017-03-03T03:53:16.2955903+00:00",
      "CreatedBy":"Jim Jones",
      "ModifiedBy":"Jim Jones",
      "ModifiedOn":"2017-02-25T07:06:32.517",
      "Deleted":false,
      "TypeId":1
   },
   {
      "EntryNo":5,
      "Title":"Old Title",
      "Summary":"Old Summary",
      "Body":"Old Body",
      "CreatedOn":"2017-03-03T03:53:16.2955903+00:00",
      "CreatedBy":"Ben Jones",
      "ModifiedBy":"Ben Jones",
      "ModifiedOn":"2017-02-25T07:06:32.593",
      "Deleted":false,
      "TypeId":1
   }
]
```

The real root of your problem is where that ill-formatted JSON came from.

Comment: So, this was a good explanation. My API, and therefore my understanding of API's was fundamentally wrong...I think. Long story short, my API was returning a list of strings. I changed to send a List<BlogVM> and deserialized in my app. Everything works now.

Comment: @RandyAugustus Glad to hear it! It's fortunate that you had the ability to change the data source, as that was the real source of your woes.